# No named parameter with the name 'textDirection'

Tags: flutter, dart, text-decorations

I tried to run my first Flutter app but received this error:
`` No named parameter with the name 'textDirection' ...` ``

After trying unsuccessful web + AI suggestions I decided to run the sample app that creates automatically in new flutter projects (VS Code) but the error remain the same.

**The code**

*The default flutter app with small change - due to the error I added the Directionality widget*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo', 
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _incrementCounter,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**The error:**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/debug.dart:354:57: Error: No named parameter with the name 'textDirection'.
        ErrorSummary('No Directionality widget found.', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,),
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/assertions.dart:310:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  ErrorSummary(super.message) : super(level: DiagnosticLevel.summary);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

**Here is the flutter doctor (flutter 3.16.9):**

```
flutter doctor   
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3007],
locale en-IL)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.8.6)
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.73.0)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources
```

What is wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: What Flutter version are you using? Can you include the result of running `flutter doctor` command?

Comment: @OmriArbel are you using the `intl` package?

Comment: @MendelG 
No. Should I use it?

Comment: @OmriArbel no. do you have any other imports bedsides for `material.dart`?

Comment: @MendelG The problem started to appear when I imported the `provider`. But in this Counter (flutter default app) I didn't import anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this part `textDirection: TextDirection.ltr` from your build method of _MyHomePageState class, so your build method will look like this.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Replace the @overide part with your code but receive the same error.

Comment: Have you replaced the build method of _MyHomePageState class, right?

Comment: Can you please share you pubspec.yaml as well?

Comment: Correct I removed the Directionality from the _MyHomePageState class.
See the pubspec.yaml in the second comment

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: zero_test
description: "A new Flutter project."
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.6 <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  analyzer: ^6.2.0
  


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  easy_localization: ^3.0.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).